# Can't Save XDocument in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, xml, silverlight, linq

I want to save a Xdocument to an xml file , and it seems that silverlight doesn't accept string type for xdoc.save(string str), so I had to put a stream inside of it , the problem is that when I put a filestream I got an error saying that "Attempt to access the method failed" and that a MethodeAccessException was unhandled here is my code :

```
XDocument MainLBItems = XDocument.Load("SampleData/MainLBItems.xml");            
            MainLBItems.Root.Add(new XElement("Item",
                                            new XElement("Title", this.tb_Title.Text),
                                            new XElement("Dscrp", this.tb_Dscrp.Text),
                                            new XElement("Count", "0")));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("SampleData/MainLBItems.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            MainLBItems.Save(fs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only used Silverlight in Windows Phone 7, but I *suspect* the same applies for desktop Silverlight... you can't use files directly as you do from the full desktop .NET framework. Instead, you have to use [isolated storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart%29). For example:

```
using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var stream = file.OpenFile("file.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        document.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

(Adjust other code using streams too.)

Comment: @Gabe: Not necessarily, no. It makes perfect sense for an application to be able to *load* its own files, but not save arbitrary data to the file system. (I don't know exactly what `XDocument.Load` will do in Silverlight anyway, to be honest.)

Comment: Hi thx Jon for your answer, it s actually silverlight in widows phone 7.1 I forgot to mention it, I tried your code anyway and it said that it s an operation not perimtted in IslatedStoregeFileStream can you please explain to me what should I do

Comment: @Daoudi: For one thing you should give more details - such as exactly which statement threw the exception and whether there is more infromation in the exception itself. This *is* the right way to save an xml file in WP7, so something is going wrong. Note that if you're still using a filename in a subdirectory, that could be causing the problem. Try some simole diagnostics to work out what's going on.

Comment: thank you Jon I resolved it , it s exactly what you predicted , I was using a filename in a subdirectory, thx again

Answer (score 0):

You can save arbitrary files to isolated storage (see MSDN for [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838189(v=VS.95).aspx)) or you can open a "Save As" dialog to ask the user for access to write to a file.

By the looks of it, you are reading an XML stream from your XAP file or the server where the XAP came from. In neither case would you be able to write back to those places.